# errors in creating Axes and Guides in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create the YAxes to the bar chart.

Now, I have finished the vScale by using:

```
var vScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([50000, yValue])
            .range([450, 0]);
```

Then, I created the VAxis and the VGuide using:

```
//V Axis
        var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(vScale)
            .ticks(10)
            .tickPadding(5);


 //V Guide
        var vGuide = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .vAxis(vGuide)
        vGuide.attr("transform", "translate(35,10)")
        vGuide.selectAll("path")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("fill", "#000")
        vGuide.selectAll("line")
            .style("stroke", "#000")
```

The result shows error the "vAxis is undefined".
I am confused about which step I did wrong. I referenced on the code about d3v3 to create the axes, but not sure how to adapt it into d3v4.

Looking forward to the detailed help. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an mistake: vGuide is a selection object and it doesn't have a method call "vAxis".

You should write like this: *vGuide = d3.select("svg").append("g").call(vAxis)*

```js
//V Guide
var vGuide = d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .vAxis(vGuide) // how could a selection have a method call "vAxis"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the axis render function incorrectly. The `vAxis` is a rendering function, it isn't something that exists on the `d3.selection`. If you look at the examples https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#api-reference then you should `.call(axisFunction)`.

Changing to this will fix your problem:

```
var vGuide = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .call(vAxis);
```